# Iterating through whole dictionary to get specific value and key

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, lambda

I am currently printing value for a specific key, like so:

```
        var myValue = dic1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "John").Value;
        Console.WriteLine("John in dictionary: " + myValue);
```

Value is numer of how many times John is in this dictionary. Now I would like to do so for whole dictionary. Any ideas? I thought about making it something like this:

```
            var dic1Dic2 = dic1.Zip(dic2, (d, z) => new { Dic1= d, Dic2 = z });
            foreach (var dz in dic1Dic2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dz.Dic1);
                Console.WriteLine(dz.Dic2);
            }
```

But in this case the problem is if one of the lists is smaller I don't get values. Hell, if one got 100 words and onther none, if will printf none.

I want to calculate like let's say in dic1 I got key = Four and value = 4, and in dic2 I got Four and value = 2 (for example, it might 4 as well, doesn't matter), and I want to multiply them, or divide or whatever. In the very basic first code example when I use only specific key value I was doing it so:

```
        var divideJohn = (myValue1 / myValue);
```

and myValue1 was from:

```
var myValue1 = dic2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "John").Value;
```

So any ideas how to get those values out of everything in dictionary?

@edit
Yeah, to clarify, I got many dictionaries, and I want values from each of them to make some math. For one dictionary making a foreach loop could be enough like so:

```
       foreach (string item in dic1.Keys)
        {
            var dif = dic1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item).Value;                                  
        }
```

But the whole point is to get them from diferent dictionaries and be able to use them in math.

Comment: `int value = dic1["Four"] * dic2["Four"]` - look up how dictionary access works, it's O(1), no need to iterate

Comment: But I want to iterate whole dictionary, not specific examples like "four" but still be able to know each result of specific example as well like "four*four".

Comment: "if one of the lists is smaller I don't get values." - what *would* you want to do  in this case? You didn't specify - otherwise using `Zip` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should then add key to another dictionary with value = 0, this could solve this problem.

Comment: not for multiplication, unless you want `0` to be the result

Comment: It is hard to really understand the use case. With a bit more context (e.g. how the data is created or what kind of math is supposed to happen), it might be easier for others to help.

Comment: I'll wait 90 minutes from this post and ask another question - if it solves the problem I'm having I will delete this post, if it will give some light onto this post I will edit this post and continue here. FOr now on let's just suspend it for some time. BTW. does deleting post automagically allows me to ask another question?

Comment: why delete it if you can just edit the question?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not really clear from your question what you are trying to do. There are a lot of details left out of your problem statement, which would unambiguously specify what the actual behavior desired is.

That said, it sounds like you are trying merge your dictionaries. A very simple version of this might be:

```
Dictionary<string, int> MergeSum(
    Dictionary<string, int> dict1, Dictionary<string, int> dict2)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> merged = new Dictionary<string, int>(dict1.Count);

    foreach (var kvp in dict1)
    {
        merged.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value + dict2[kvp.Key]);
    }
}
```

Note in the above there is the implicit assumption that both dictionaries contain exactly the same keys. An alternative that doesn't make this assumption might look like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> MergeSum(
    Dictionary<string, int> dict1, Dictionary<string, int> dict2)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> merged = new Dictionary<string, int>(dict1.Count);

    foreach (var kvp in dict1)
    {
        int value;

        dict2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value);
        merged.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value + value);
    }

    foreach (var kvp in dict2)
    {
        int value;

        if (!dict1.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value))
        {
            merged.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `value` will be set to 0 if it's not present in the dictionary when `TryGetValue()` is called.

In your question, you seem to indicate that you may have more than two dictionaries to merge. In that case, you can take as input an array of dictionaries (or other collection…array is just convenient for the purpose of illustration):

```
Dictionary<string, int> MergeSum(Dictionary<string, int>[] dictionaries)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> merged = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (Dictionary<string, int> dict in dictionaries)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            int value;

            merged.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value);
            merged[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value + value;
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to do any of the above with other operations, in a general-purpose way. That might look something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> Merge(
    Dictionary<string, int>[] dictionaries, Func<int, int, int> mergeFunction)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> merged = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (Dictionary<string, int> dict in dictionaries)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            int value;

            merged.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value);
            merged[kvp.Key] = mergeFunction(value, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

You might call the above like this:

```
result = Merge(dictionaries, (i1, i2) => i1 + i2);
```

Some operations are more problematic than others. For example, if you are using multiplication, then since the code always aggregates from the empty initial dictionary, the aggregation operation result would always be 0. You can address this by special-casing the first dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> Merge(
    Dictionary<string, int>[] dictionaries, Func<int, int, int> mergeFunction)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> merged = new Dictionary<string, int>(dictionaries.First());

    foreach (Dictionary<string, int> dict in dictionaries.Skip(1))
    {
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            int value;

            merged.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value);
            merged[kvp.Key] = mergeFunction(value, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

That will initialize the `merged` dictionary with the first dictionary in the collection, and then will skip that dictionary when doing the actual aggregation loop. But note that even there, you have potential issues when dealing with keys not present in each dictionary (e.g. if multiplying, you'll get 0 in the final result if any dictionary is missing that key). Of course, maybe that's what you really want.

Note also that the above all assumes your values are `int`. But there's not really anything about most of the code that assumes that. As long as you have some valid way of combining a pair of values, you can easily modify the above code to do whatever you want. That includes a fully generic version of the final example:

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Merge<TKey, TValue>(
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue>[] dictionaries, Func<TValue, TValue, TValue> mergeFunction)
{
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> merged = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionaries.First());

    foreach (Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict in dictionaries.Skip(1))
    {
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            TValue value;

            merged.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value);
            merged[kvp.Key] = mergeFunction(kvp.Value, value);
        }
    }
}
```

(Disclaimer: none of the above code has been compiled. I apologize in advance for any typographical errors, and presume that figuring what I really meant won't be too difficult :) ).

Finally, note that there is the [`Enumerable.ToDictionary()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.100).aspx). I have written the general logic out above, but you may find that you can use various LINQ operations, including the `ToDictionary()` method, to simplify the code and make it more expressive of your actual intent (i.e. such that the code shows more of *what* you want to do, rather than *how* it is done).